# How can I add more than one network interface to vexpress-a15 machine in qemu

Tags: arm, qemu

I am trying to create an ARM virtual machine for my code and I want to have at least 3 network interfaces in the VM (bridged to interfaces in the host), I tried to do it in many different ways but again and again, it get only 1 interface (eth0)
I tried to run qemu in this way:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -m 2048M -M vexpress-a15 -cpu cortex-a15 -kernel zImage -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb -no-reboot -initrd initramfs.cpio.anp.gz -nographic  -append 'console=ttyAMA0,115200' -net nic,name=eth0 -net tap,ifname=tap0 -net nic,name=eth1 -net tap,ifname=tap1}
```

but I get only eth0 in my guest OS.

How can I add eth1/eth2 to the VM?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with vexpress-a15 -- it is a model of a specific development board which in hardware has only one ethernet adaptor and no PCI bus you could use to plug more ethernet devices into.

Unless you have a strong requirement to use vexpress-a15 in particular I would recommend using the "virt" board instead, which is much more flexible and in particular has a PCI bus that you can use to provide the number of ethernet devices you need. (You'll probably need to rebuild your kernel appropriately and you'll need to tweak your commandline too.)

Comment: I chose vexpress-a15 because my software is running on a physical device that have Alpine SoC which is based on cotrex-a15. I think it is not a MUST requirement for me to use vexpress-a15. Suppose I want to use the "-M virt". My question is how should I compile my linux kernel? what "defconfig" should I use?

Comment: Just because the SoC you are interested in uses the Cortex-A15 does not mean it is going to look anything like the devices the vexpress-a15 has. The "virt" board also permits running with a Cortex-A15, for instance (and looks different from vexpress-a15). QEMU has no model of the Alpine SoC, so you would need to either (a) write device models for it (a lot of work) or (b) don't try to run the kernel for that SoC and instead use a kernel for the QEMU virt board -- this should work if your userspace software doesn't care what hardware it is running on.

Comment: how can I "use a kernel for the QEMU virt board"? what defconfig should I use to compile my kernel?